# How to use and update same variable across multiple modules in python independently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, global-variables

I have 3 files and I want to do something like below

[1] conf.py

```py
var = 10  # Intialized with 10 (start)
```

[2] file_1.py

```py
import conf
print(conf.var)   # Prints 10
conf.var = 1000   # Updated to 1000
```

[3] file_2.py

```py
import conf
print(conf.var)   # Prints 1000
conf.var = 9999   # Updated to 9999
```

I want something like this. Assume that the files, file_1 and file_2 `will be running and will stay in memory unless pressed CTRL+C`. How can I change `var` in other 2 files and persist the value for it? Final value for `var` should be 9999 if we were to use it in file_3 like other 2 files. [It should print 9999] and so on.

Execution order `file_1.py -> file_2.py`.

Help me with identifying some way to do it or some module/package that can handle this.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You can't use modules for interprocess communication like this. The *file* `conf.py` is used to initialize independent `conf` modules in the two processes created from `file1.py` and `file2.py`.

Comment: There are lot of smart ways to share data between two executions. One very simple and straight forward to be to read and write from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on this problem. I will suggest to use shared memory cache providers like `Redis` or `memcached`. Both start a server instance that we need to connect and use it like a key-value store. Note than values should be of type `str` or `bytes`.

## Memcached

###### Install `memcached`

```sh
sudo apt install memcached
```

###### Start Server with default settings

You need to start the server before using it or you can set it as a service in linux

```
sudo service memcached start
```

###### Install python memcached client

```
pip install pymemcache
```

###### Sample Code

```py
from pymemcache.client import base

client = base.Client(('localhost', 11211))
client.set('some_key', 'stored value')

client.get('some_key')  # Returns "stored value"
```

## Redis

The process is exact same for redis

###### Install `redis`

```sh
sudo apt install redis
```

###### Start Server with default settings

You need to start the server before using it or you can set it as a service in linux

```
sudo service redis start
```

###### Install python redis client

```
pip install redis
```

###### Sample Code

```py
import redis

client = redis.Redis()  # Default settings/credentials
client.set('some_key', 'stored value')

client.get('some_key')  # Returns "stored value"
```

## Usage

- Redis gives more safety and fault tolerance.
- Both has some memory limits but is configurable. If your data is more in size, use files or db suitable to your problem.
- Both are easy to configure

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use a class and never initialize an object?

```
class Conf:
    var = 10
```

You would then update Conf with:

`from conf import Conf`

...

`Conf.var = ...`

Just never use `Conf()...`, as this creates an object instance.

Comment: Nope. Not working!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach:

```
class Lookup:
    # For allowing storing and looking up variables using variable sets of key pairs.
    # Each key pair is a key-value pair tuple.
    # The entire set of key pair tuples uniquely stores and retreives a variable value.
    # frozenset is used to achieve the benifit of a set while ensuring immutability, so it can be hashed for use as a dictionary key.
    lookupDictionary = {}
    def put(*, keyPairs, value):
        Lookup.lookupDictionary[frozenset(keyPairs)] = value
    def get(*, keyPairs, default, matchWildcard = False): # No substring searching. only '*' can be used for searching for an entire string
        if matchWildcard and True in [bool(x) for x in [(y[1] == '*') for y in keyPairs]]:
            # If we are here, we need to match using wildcard. 
            valuedKeyPairs = set([y for y in keyPairs if not y[1] == '*'])  # Separating value pairs from wildcard pairs
            starKeyPairs = set(keyPairs) - valuedKeyPairs
            starKeyPairNames = [x[0] for x in starKeyPairs]
            return [Lookup.lookupDictionary[i] for i in Lookup.lookupDictionary.keys() if set(valuedKeyPairs).issubset(i) and sorted(starKeyPairNames) == sorted([x[0] for x in i-valuedKeyPairs])]
        return Lookup.lookupDictionary.get(frozenset(keyPairs), default)
    def getAllValues(*, keyPairs):
        # Returrns all qualifying values to part or all of the key pairs
        return [Lookup.lookupDictionary[i] for i in set(Lookup.lookupDictionary.keys()) if set(keyPairs).issubset(i)]
class utils:
    def setCacheEntry(*, zipFileName, functionName, value):
        Lookup.put(keyPairs = [('__zipFileName__',zipFileName),('__functionName__',functionName)],value=value)

    def getCacheEntry(*, zipFileName, functionName, default):
        return Lookup.get(keyPairs = [('__zipFileName__',zipFileName),('__functionName__',functionName)],default=default)
```

```
from Lookup import utils
from Lookup import Lookup
utils.setCacheEntry(zipFileName='FileName.zip',functionName='some_func',value='some_value')
utils.getCacheEntry(zipFileName='FileName.zip',functionName='some_func', default=1)
```

Output:
'some_value'

**This is a more simple case:**

```
from Lookup import Lookup

def setParamValue(*, paramName, value):
    Lookup.put(keyPairs = [('__paramName__',paramName),],value=value)
    
def getParamValue(*, paramName, default):
    return Lookup.get(keyPairs = [('__paramName__',paramName),],default=default, matchWildcard=True)
    
setParamValue(paramName='name', value='John')
setParamValue(paramName='age', value=23)
```

```
getParamValue(paramName='name', default='Unknown')
```

Output: John

```
getParamValue(paramName='age', default=-1)
```

Output: 23

```
getParamValue(paramName='*', default='Unknown')
```

Output: ['John', 23]

**If you need to communicate variables/objects between different programs,
the above does not work.**
To do it you may use pickle to dump and load objects across the OS:
I have not tested it to see if it does deep or shallow dumping of objects, but probably the later.

```
import pickle

# Dumping

with open('object_pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump('some_value', f)    

# Loading
    
with open('object_pickle','rb') as f2:
    var = pickle.load(f2)

print(var)
```

Output: 'some_value'

Comment: I shared this with the test case on github: https://github.com/mhega/Sampy

Comment: This works if the modules that are accessing the Lookup class are all in the same program run - e.g., fired from a single common module.

Comment: If you aren't accessing in the same program run, you're going to need to save the data somewhere and i/o from that file. What you're describing just isn't possible with modules.

Comment: This approach is not intended for inter-process communication between modules that are run within different executions. But to your comment that it is not possible, this link demonstrates how this works to communicate variables between modules that are commonly imported within the same program run (https://github.com/mhega/Sampy/blob/main/Lookup.ipynb)

Comment: I edited the answer suggesting one way to save/access variables thru the OS (using pickle), but that is independent of the Lookup class. The Lookup works only to communicate between different modules that are imported within the same program run.

Comment: You said that "This works if the modules that are accessing the Lookup class are all in the same program run," implying you needed them to work in different program runs, which is impossible to my knowledge without saving something. Using pickle saves something.

Comment: Just to clarify: when I used "zipFileName" in the example in my answer, I did not mean to imply that I am saving anything to a zip file. This was the example from my project where I cached the analysis of a zip file (logs), so other modules within the same application would avoid redoing the analysis of the same file. You are correct to communicate across program runs, objects have to be saved somewhere